# I want to make a global variable only accessible after certain conditions have been met

Tags: python-3.x

So i want to make a simple game with a login system and i need to be able to use global variables. however i want to make it so them variables only accessible after certain conditions have been met which in this case is after getting the information from the original function. I need to store the information in the login code and then. use it in the game function.

```
mport sqlite3, time, sys
import random as rnd

givenusername = input("Player 1 please enter your username: ")
givenpassword = input("please enter your password: ")
givenusername2 = input("Player 2 please enter your username: ")
givenpassword2 = input("please enter your password: ")

print('Loading gamefunctions.py')
Error1 = "Error 1: No information given or incorrect please try again"
Error2 = "Error 2: Not implemented"
Error3 = "Username and password not found"

def menu():
    print('''Menu:
             A - Account create
             B - Login and play
             C - Quit
          ''')
    choice = input()
    if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
        accountcreate()
    elif choice == 'b' or choice == 'B':
        login()

    elif choice == 'c' or choice == 'C':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(Error1)
        sys.exit()


def accountcreate():
    found = 0
    while found == 0:
        newuser = input('Choose a username you would like to use: ')
        with sqlite3.connect("login.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
        findUser = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username =?")
        cursor.execute(findUser, [(newuser)])  #
        if cursor.fetchall():
            print("Username taken, please try again")
            accountcreate()
        else:
            found = 1

        newpass = input('Now choose a password you want to use to login to the game: ')
        newpass2 = input('Now repeat that same password to finish account setup: ')
        if newpass != newpass2:
            print(Error1)
            time.sleep(4)
            newpass = input('Now choose a password you want to use to login to the game: ')
            newpass2 = input('Now repeat that same password to finish account setup: ')
        if newpass == newpass2:
            insertData = ('''INSERT INTO user(username, password)
            VALUES(?,?)''')
            cursor.execute(insertData, [(newuser), (newpass2)])
            db.commit()
            print("Account created")


def login():
    while True:
        global givenusername
        global givenpassword
        with sqlite3.connect("login.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            find_user = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
            cursor.execute(find_user, [givenusername, givenpassword])
            result = cursor.fetchall()

        if result:
            for i in result:
                print("Welcome " + i[0])
                login2()

        else:
            print(Error3)
            again = input("Do you want to try again? (Y/N)")
            if again.lower() == "n":
                print("Goodbye")
                time.sleep(1)
                return ("exit")
            else:
                login()
def login2():
    loggedin = False
    if loggedin == True:
        global givenpassword2
        global givenusername2
        with sqlite3.connect("login.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
        cursor.execute(find_user, [givenusername2, givenpassword2])
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        if result:
            for i in result:
                print("Welcome " + i[0])
                game()

        else:
            print(Error3)
            again = input("Do you want to try again? (Y/N)")
            if again.lower() == "n":
                print("Goodbye")
                time.sleep(1)
                return "exit"

def game():
    playonescore = 0
    playertwoscore = 0
 ## initialising dice
    die1number = rnd.randint(1,6)
    die2number = rnd.randint(1,6)
 ## round 1




    print(die1number, die2number)
    print(playertwoscore)
    print(playonescore)
```

The usernames and passwords at the top is what i want to save after BOTH login functions have been completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the conditions before using `global var`

Example:

```
if varGlobal == True:
    global var
```

Comment: Would that work after the login2() has been completed? and i need the givenusername's to be what each person has entered.